# CountIf statement which checks a row of values for any meeting a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, formula, formulas

I am working on a formula to count and increment if the value in A10:A610 is "yes" and any value in that particular row is over lets say like 2.
For example:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I

Yes     5   1   4   3   1   2   7
No      3   2   3   4   2   5   3
Yes     5   1   1   1   1   0   1
Yes     1   0   1   0   1   1   1
```

Should return 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry about the formatting. Just couldn't get it right

Comment: See if my edit makes it better or not and feel free to edit it again

Comment: Can you explain more how is the expected output is 2 for your example?

Comment: @zx8754 Row 1 and 3 have "Yes" and have `5` in the row as well, so they qualify. Row 4 has only 1 and 0, meaning no value exceeding 2, hence it doesn't qualify.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is with a helper column:

Following will give you 1 if it qualifies otherwise 0. Then you just have to get the SUM for this column.

Copy and paste this to `I2`

`=IF(AND(A2="Yes",COUNTIF(B2:H2,">2")>0),1,0)`

I would like to see all in one cell solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply zx8754 but your solution doesnt work if i use range A10:A610. For some reason, it keeps returning 1. Remembr, i want to check the entire file, not just values in A2.

Comment: Above formula must be entered on every row on `I` column, then at the bottom get the `SUM` for column `I`.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear zx8754, but what i need is a one cell solution which would check the entire file and return a summary count :)

Comment: +1 since this is a working solution and there was no mention of single cell formula in the question originally.

Answer (score 1):

I've got something, but it's quite lengthy. I could not find a way to add values in a row of an array only and not add across the columns as well. Nevertherless, it works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5="Yes"),
    IF((B1:B5<3)*(C1:C5<3)*(D1:D5<3)*(E1:E5<3)*(F1:F5<3)*(G1:G5<3)*(H1:H5<3),0,1)
)
```

This is an array formula, so you'll have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it work properly or you'll get `#VALUE!`.

[image]

I'm using the property of `0` here that anything when multiplied by 0 becomes zero, and reverse the result later on with the `if( (...), 0, 1)`.

So, if all the values are true (all the values are less than 3), then return `0` (or false if you want) otherwise, return 1 (or true).

You'll notice that this has another limitation aside to the length, is that it will work with integers only. If you have 2.5 somewhere, you would require it to be counted, but this formula won't. You can change that (and making the formula a bit longer yet!) by changing all the `<3` in the `IF()`to `<=2` if you don't have only integers, but that's it.

Comment: Oh and change the references to the proper ones. I'm using the range `1:5` here.

Comment: +1 for `SUMPRODUCT` solution, I had a feeling I had to use it but then went for an easy way of "helper columns" :)

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks! It was tough to come up with that one though, I sat for a good 10 minutes I think before making up that formula!

Comment: Aha...so if i decided to modify the formula to find the values BELOW 2 now. How could that be achieved?

Comment: @nigelcarter You simply reverse the logic, meaning you replace all the `<=2` to `>=2`. If you have integers, you can use `>1` instead.

Comment: Thats what I thought Jerry, but it doesnt work
Im using your formula to find the count of rows with values greater than 11538 and that works fine.
="("&SUMPRODUCT(--(A10:A610="Yes"),IF((E10:E610<=11538)*(F10:F610<=11538)*(G10:G610<=11538)*(H10:H610<=11538)*(I10:I610<=11538),0,1))&")"

However, when i try to capture the count of rows with values below 11539 by reversing the formula to 
="("&SUMPRODUCT(--(A10:A610="Yes"),IF((E10:E610>=11539)*(F10:F610>=11539)*(G10:G610>=11539)*(H10:H610>=11538)*(I10:I610>=11539),0,1))&")"
it just doesnt work, it returns a wrong count. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @nigelcarter Are you sure? It's working fine for me. Did you test it against the sample you provided? Since all the rows have at least one value below 2, it returns a count of 3. Or should the count be different there? If so, you'll need to get another formula. One thing that might make things easier is to make the "greater than" be a reference. See this picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9co34.png. I'm saying this because one value in your formula is `11538` instead of `11539`.

Comment: @Jerry in your example in the link, please change A2 to yes and see what happens

Comment: @nigelcarter Sure, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/ntw7x.png Above 2 becomes 3 since row 2 has at least one value above 2. Below 2 remains 3 since row 2 has no value below 2.